# Looking for an app that will play a custom MP3 at scheduled times?

Tags: audio, ios

I feel like there must already be some built-in scheduling function for this, but I just can't find it.   I want to play a music clip (custom audio MP3) for my dog every day at 11 am, looking for a way to automate this, so I can just set it up on an old phone and let it play daily.

For the life of me, I just can't find anything....please help.

Comment: There are a few but it depends on your phone.  Android  Apple or other?

Comment: Would prefer iOS, but definitely open to Android solutions too.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As your tags indicate iOS, one can pursue the ringtone option built into the Apple architecture.

One can set an alarm for every day, at a specific time. The next step is to assign the desired ringtone representing the custom audio clip to that alarm. This feature is built into the alarm settings, specific for the time referenced for the alarm.

A [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVLk1aSQVU4) showing the process of converting a song to a ringtone involves a ringtone app (free) and converting using GarageBand. It appears rather convoluted, but is a sound solution, no pun intended.

The above process references a 30 second time limit, but searching that set of terms shows another process to increase the limitation, should your desired song be longer than 30 seconds.

I've taken a more direct route (possibly not more direct) by using Audacity to import the audio clip/song. Editing is straight forward in Audacity. Once completed, save the file as .M4A (.m4a) format. Rename the file to .M4R (.m4r) and transfer to the Apple device. I've found it easier to use iTunes to drag and drop the .m4r file to the ringtones section of the device, although it can be emailed to the device as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I haven't thought about the alarm feature before.  Yea, I have a song that my dog likes to listen to, we "sang" it together (lol), it is like 3 minutes long.  When I play it manually, I loop it for him and he listens for like 20 minutes a day.